# DrRacket Filtering a list without filter function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'll preface this by saying this is for an assignment for class, but I've done quite a bit of research on the official Racket site(as well as notes) and nothing seems to be working.

I'm trying to filter out a given list and return only values that satisfy the parameters of a given function f.

Right now I have:

```
(define (remove-cond f l)
        (if (null? l) l)
            (filter f l)))
```

I saw that the filter function does exactly what I need it to do(taken right from the Racket site), but it's showing as undefined in R5RS. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I also had the idea of rewriting the map function as it will return #t/#f values. I was thinking of having it return the list element if #t, and nothing if #f, but I'm not sure how to approach that.

Comment: `(if (condition-holds? element) (cons element recursive-result) recursive-result)`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is in the [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/) textbook.  The most relevant section is [section 10.1](http://www.htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/part_two.html#%28part._sec~3alist-produce%29), but in order to use it, you're probably going to have to back up and do the reading about the design recipe and the template.